# Magento User Permision Access denied

Tags: magento

I am getting this error on Facebook pixel extention for users otherthan admin

**Access denied
Please try to logout and sign in again.
If this message persists, please contact the store**

I have removed acl from adminhtml file 
(file path *app/code/community/Facebook/AdsToolbox/etc/adminhtml.xml*)

and added this to all controller classes

```
 protected function _isAllowed() {
     return true; }
```

it worked fine but now again it is giving me the same access denied error. Please help

adminhtml.xml code

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <config>
      <menu>
        <facebook_ads_toolbox translate="title"
          module="Facebook_AdsToolbox">
          <title>Facebook Ads Extension</title>
          <sort_order>72</sort_order>
          <action>adminhtml/fbmain/index</action>
        </facebook_ads_toolbox>
      </menu>

    </config>
```

Config.XML code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <config>
- <modules>
- <Facebook_AdsToolbox>
  <version>2.1.15</version> 
  </Facebook_AdsToolbox>
  </modules>
- <global>
- <models>
- <Facebook_AdsToolbox>
  <class>Facebook_AdsToolbox_Model</class> 
  </Facebook_AdsToolbox>
  </models>
- <blocks>
- <Facebook_AdsToolbox>
  <class>Facebook_AdsToolbox_Block</class> 
  </Facebook_AdsToolbox>
  </blocks>
- <helpers>
- <Facebook_AdsToolbox>
  <class>Facebook_AdsToolbox_Helper</class> 
  </Facebook_AdsToolbox>
  </helpers>
- <events>
- <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
- <observers>
- <Facebook_AdsToolbox_Cart_Observer>
  <type>object</type> 
  <class>Facebook_AdsToolbox_Model_Observer</class> 
  <method>addToCart</method> 
  </Facebook_AdsToolbox_Cart_Observer>
  </observers>
  </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
- <controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml>
- <observers>
- <Facebook_AdsToolbox_NoCache_Observer>
  <type>object</type> 
  <class>Facebook_AdsToolbox_Model_Observer</class> 
  <method>disableCache</method> 
  </Facebook_AdsToolbox_NoCache_Observer>
  </observers>
  </controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml>
  </events>
  </global>
- <frontend>
- <layout>
- <updates>
- <FacebookAdsToolbox module="Facebook_AdsToolbox">
  <file>facebookadstoolbox.xml</file> 
  </FacebookAdsToolbox>
  </updates>
  </layout>
- <routers>
- <facebook_debug>
  <use>standard</use> 
- <args>
  <module>Facebook_AdsToolbox</module> 
  <frontName>facebookadstoolbox</frontName> 
  </args>
  </facebook_debug>
  </routers>
  </frontend>
- <admin>
- <routers>
- <adminhtml>
- <args>
- <modules>
  <Pixel after="Mage_Adminhtml">Facebook_AdsToolbox_Adminhtml</Pixel> 
  </modules>
  </args>
  </adminhtml>
  </routers>
  </admin>
- <adminhtml>
- <layout>
- <updates>
- <FacebookAdsToolbox module="Facebook_AdsToolbox_Adminhtml">
  <file>facebookadstoolbox.xml</file> 
  </FacebookAdsToolbox>
  </updates>
  </layout>
  </adminhtml>
- <crontab>
- <jobs>
- <facebookadstoolbox_feed_regenerate>
- <schedule>
  <cron_expr>59 00 * * *</cron_expr> 
  </schedule>
- <run>
  <model>Facebook_AdsToolbox/observer::generateFacebookProductFeed</model> 
  </run>
  </facebookadstoolbox_feed_regenerate>
  </jobs>
  </crontab>
  </config>
```

Comment: please update question with `config.xml` code

Comment: done please check

Comment: You haven't create **acl** for your module you should write it in `config.xml` or `adminhtml.xml` file. Reference link : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45141/how-to-add-acl-in-custom-module-in-magento